# How do I change a value for a key at a specific index?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have been stuck trying to figure out how to change a value for a key at a specific index. For example if I have the following data,

```
Index |  slideNumber  |  Title
--------------------------------------------
1     |      5        |  test 1
2     |      2        |  test 2
3     |      5        |  test 3
4     |      7        |  test 4
5     |      9        |  test 5
```

If I want to change the value of slideNumber at index 3, how would I do that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you say "value for a key at a specific index" - how are you storing these indices, slideNumbers and titles in your app? Are you using an NSDictionary, an NSArray, or some other structure?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit (thanks for the suggestion @morningstar):

This would probably be a quicker way to do it:

```
- (void)newSlideNumber:(NSInteger)slideNumber 
              forIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Slides" 
                                   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Index == %d", index]];
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request 
                                                                error:&error];

    [request release];
    if ([results count]) {
        [(NSManagedObject *)[results objectAtIndex:0] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:slideNumber] 
                                                        forKey:@"slideNumber"];
    } else if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"predicateWithFormat (Index == %d) did not match any objects!", index);
    }
}
```

---

### Orig

Are you doing this with CoreData?  If so, here is a guide (untested and probably wont work exactly as it is if copy/pasted.  Just to be used as an example):

```
- (void)newSlideNumber:(NSInteger)slideNumber forIndex:(NSInteger)index withTitle:(NSString *)title {
    NSError *error = NULL;
    // Delete the objects first, then recreate them:
    [self deleteObjectsForEntityNamewithPred:@"MyEntityName" withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Index == %d", index]]; // This method is the one defined below

    // Get the managed object from your context:
    NSManagedObject *managedObjectStore = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntityName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    // Set the new values:
    [managedObjectStore setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index] forKey:@"Index"];
    [managedObjectStore setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:slideNumber] forKey:@"slideNumber"];
    [managedObjectStore setValue:title forKey:@"Title"];

    // Save the context
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    }
}


- (void)deleteObjectsForEntityNamewithPred:(NSString *)entityName withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)pred {
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [request release];
    if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    }
    for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in results) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
    }
}
```

Some Reference Docs:

[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html)

[NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html)

[NSManagedObjectModel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

---

Comment: Deleting the objects is probably not the best way. Just write code like in your second function, but instead of `[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject]`, do `[managedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:slideNumber] forKey:@"slideNumber"]`. It's not necessary to delete and recreate an object just to set one property. It would also be more complicated if there are relationships to the object, and even more so if there are "weak" relationships somewhere that have stored the object's objectID for referring to it later.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm a newbie, this was what I needed, got it working! I just needed to use a predicate to zero in on the object I wanted to modify, makes a lot more sense now, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Core Data Entity has three attributes: index, slideNumber, title

You can retrieve the correct entity (an instance of a row in that table if you are thinking like a database which I recommend against) with the following code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ...;
NSInteger myIndex = 3;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"index == %i", myIndex]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error && !results) {
  NSLog(@"Error %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
NSManagedObject *myEntity = [results lastObject];
```

Now that we have the entity, editing a value is a simple KVC call away:

```
[myEntity setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:5 forKey:@"slideNumber"];
```

From there, you will probably want to save your changes:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ...;
NSError *error = nil;
if (![moc save:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"Error %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

It is best to think of Core Data as an object graph and **NOT** as a table in a database.  The database is just a means to persist the data.

I also recommend reading up on KVC (Key Value Coding).  You can avoid using KVC if you want by subclassing your `NSManagedObjects` but it is unnecessary.